# Trigger a certain key combo with another one

Tags: xorg, keyboard, xmodmap, xdotool

Can anyone suggest me on what would be the best way to trigger a certain key kombo with another one. Say, I'd like to send CTRL+= while pressing CTRL+[.
Basically I want to workaround zoom for Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Esc</kbd> (i. e. `^[`) is not a shift-type key such as <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, or <kbd>Meta</kbd>.  These latter keys alter the character code sent by *another* key sent in when pressed in combination *with* them.  For instance, the character sent by <kbd>]</kbd> (`]`) is a different character from that sent by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (`^]`), which is in turn different from that sent with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (`}`).  <kbd>Esc</kbd> *is* itself a character, and cannot be *combined* with another character; merely sent *in sequence* (i .e. before or after) with them.

Comment: I see, however CTRL+[ could be bound to trigger some action, is it not possible to trigger another key combo?

Answer (score 0):

If your distribution has xbindkeys in its repositories, you could easily combine it with xdotool.